# Add locale to a route with slug [symfony2]

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization, twig, jms

I'm trying to translate the page of my website, i used the bundle `JMSI18nRoutingBundle`, but when i'm trying to reach certain pages of the website i have the following error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "page_slug" as such
>   route does not exist.") in
>   SonataPageBundle:Block:block_container.html.twig at line 15.

I noticed that i have the error with the pages that have a block of content that is stored in the database.

I'm using `SonataPageBundle` and `SonataBlockBundle` to edit certain page of the website.

here Below 2 routes that giving me the error:

```
privacy_policy:
    path: /privacy_policy
    defaults:  {  _controller: FLYBookingsBundle:Default:privacypolicy }


product:
    pattern: /product/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: FLYBookingsBundle:Post:product }
```

.

```
<li><a href="{{ path('privacy_policy') }}">Privacy Policy</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read `documentation` http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/master/usage:

```
<a href="{{ path("homepage", {"_locale": "de"}) }}">Deutsch</a>
```

or

```
product:
    pattern: /{_locale}/product/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: FLYBookingsBundle:Post:product }
    requirements:
         _locale: en|fr
    defaults: { _locale: en }
```

Comment: I just tried with your example but still doesn't work, i'm still having the same error. I'm having this error with all page that content a block of sonataBlock. I'm using sonata page to edit block of content.

Comment: I also tried like this: `<li><a href="{{ path('privacy_policy', {'_locale': app.request.attributes.get('_locale')}) }}">Privacy Policy</a></li>` , but still having the same error  :(